# how communequer between a mobile application and a PC application and what i use as data base?

Tags: java, android, swig

I have two application (java) on two PCs and a mobile application (Android)

My problem is the interaction between different applications with the database:
- Between PC and PC
- PC and mobile

PC <---------> BD -------------> Mobile

What data base i use to connect and transfer data between the two. **this is a remote communication.**
PC <--------------> base <------------------> Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any specific reason for using two different pcs?
Assuming if you have two application, you can deploy them in one PC and have DB in the same PC.

The design of the application should be like this.
1) Develop a REST/SOAP based Webservice application which talk to DB.
2) Deploy this application in Application server.
2) In your android application user REST/SOAP based webservice client to talk to the webservice hosted in step 2.

Comment: I will test the 3 application on the same pc and perhaps I will use VirtualBox

but in reality 2 application on two pc. to enter a user's data and one for the visit. 3rd and mobile application for receipt, data